# Enumerate: only indent numbers

Tags: spacing, indentation, enumerate

I want to make the `enumerate` environment look like this:

```
    1. First item [...]
[first item continued]
    2. Second item [...]
```

That is, the text should look like normal body text except with indented numbers. I'd like to be able to control the vertical spacing between items as well, so that I have the option of changing it from the default value to zero.

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
   \item \lipsum[1]
   \item \lipsum[2]
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `leftmargin` of `0pt` and non-zero `itemindent` works:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=0pt,itemindent=2em]
  \item \lipsum[2]
  \item \lipsum[4]
\end{enumerate}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Vertical spacing between items can be set via `itemsep`.

Comment: You'll need to change `itemsep` *and* `parsep` to get the desired output. And, for consistency, it would be better to do `\setlist[enumerate]{leftmargin=0pt,itemindent=2em,parsep=0pt,itemsep=0pt}`.

Answer (score 4):

This is not dissimilar to Werner's answer but the item labels do not spill back into the margin. That is, if you add `align=left`, the item numbers will be flush left and aligned with the text area rather than to the left of the text area. I find this theoretically more satisfying but admit this is likely irrational!

I've also set the paragraph indent for the list. If you drop the vertical separation between items, you'll want to do so between paragraphs within an item as well, as Gonzalo Medina points out. But you still need something to distinguish paragraph breaks so you will want to stop the list environment setting the paragraph indent to zero.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,lipsum}
\begin{document}
  \lipsum[1]
  \begin{enumerate}[labelindent=0pt, labelwidth=*, leftmargin=0pt, itemindent=!, itemsep=0pt, parsep=0pt, listparindent=\parindent]
    \item \lipsum[2]
    \item \lipsum[4-5]
  \end{enumerate}

  \lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image: list]

## EDIT

As Gonzalo Medina points out in comments, it is easier to use such settings consistently if you set them globally in your preamble.

I would do this by creating a new list environment with these settings:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{mylist}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[mylist]{labelindent=0pt, labelwidth=*, leftmargin=0pt, itemindent=!, itemsep=0pt, parsep=0pt, listparindent=\parindent}
...
```

This would then enable me to use the environment `mylist` in the document itself:

```
\begin{mylist}
  \item ...
\end{mylist}
```

So to create the above example, I'd use this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{mylist}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[mylist]{label={\arabic*.}, labelindent=0pt, labelwidth=*, leftmargin=0pt, itemindent=!, itemsep=0pt, parsep=0pt, listparindent=\parindent}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
  \lipsum[1]
  \begin{mylist}
    \item \lipsum[2]
    \item \lipsum[4-5]
  \end{mylist}

  \lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

If you *only* want this type of numbered list, then you could instead change the default settings for `enumerate` in the preamble with:

```
\setlist[enumerate]{labelindent=0pt, labelwidth=*, leftmargin=0pt, itemindent=!, itemsep=0pt, parsep=0pt, listparindent=\parindent}
```

or

```
\setlist[enumerate,1]{labelindent=0pt, labelwidth=*, leftmargin=0pt, itemindent=!, itemsep=0pt, parsep=0pt, listparindent=\parindent}
```

which will only use these settings for the first level enumeration.

Comment: Again, for consistency, it'd be better to do `\setlist[enumerate]{labelindent=0pt, labelwidth=*, leftmargin=0pt, itemindent=!, itemsep=0pt, parsep=0pt, listparindent=\parindent}` in the preamble.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I guess if you are sure you don't want the regular `enumerate` settings... If I wanted to use these settings multiple times, I'd be more inclined to do `\newlist{mylist}{enumerate}{1}` and then `\setlist[mylist]{labelindent=0pt, labelwidth=*, leftmargin=0pt, itemindent=!, itemsep=0pt, parsep=0pt, listparindent=\parindent}` and use `\begin{mylist}...\end{mylist}` in the document itself.

Comment: The first OP's sentence suggests that the settings are to be applied to all the `enumerate` environments; in any case, a global setting (either for `enumerate` or for a new list) is preferable, in my opinion.

Comment: The same result can be obtained setting the shorter options: `[wide=\parindent,noitemsep]`. Writing `nosep` instead of no itemsep gives a text which perfectly undistinguishable from ordinary text except numbering.

Comment: @Bernard Huh. Thanks. I didn't know about `wide`. (I see it is marked as 'new' in the manual but I also see it must be at least 3 years ago!)